# Xamarin Realm PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm

I've installed Realm via Nuget into my Xamarin PCL and my Android project, and when I try to run any lines of Realm code I get the following exception:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The PCL build of Realm is being linked which probably means you need to use NuGet or otherwise link a platform-specific Realm.dll to your main application.
```

I've studied the various Realm forums, the typical suggestion is to make sure each device project also has the Realm package  installed into it, which I already have, so that isn't the solution. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up your csproj files for each of the platform specific projects. Make sure that the dll referenced in there comes from the platform specific folder in the NuGet package.

If you are seeing this error you will most likely see it coming from `portable-net45+sl5+wp8+wpa81+win8+monoandroid+Xamarin.iOS10+Xamarin.Mac`.

You would want that reference to point at MonoAndroid44, Xamarin.iOS10, Xamarin.Mac etc. Not the portable. Fix this, and you will fix your exception.

Comment: I've got this in the Android project for the Realm Version: `<HintPath>..\..\packages\Realm.0.82.1\lib\MonoAndroid44\Realm.dll</HintPath>`

Comment: I've marked this as the answer, whilst it wasn't quite correct it did directly lead me to the solution: it wasn't the Realm DLL misdirection that was causing the error, but the Remotion.Linq DLL. My Android project file contained the following: `<Reference Include="Remotion.Linq, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fee00910d6e5f53b, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Remotion.Linq.2.1.1\lib\portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80\Remotion.Linq.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>`, the "portable-net45..." bit should read "MonoAndroid44"